# Construct a DFA which accepts all strings containing both 11 and 010 as substrings

Tags: complexity-theory, finite-automata

I have drawn the DFA for language L1 containing 11 as substring and language L2 containing 010 as substring. But I don't know how to concatenate these two to get the final answer. Please help!

Comment: Use the product construction.

Comment: Okay thank you! @YuvalFilmus

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can't we use concatenation?

Comment: The concatenation $L_1L_2$ doesn't contain 01011, for instance.

Comment: @RickDecker oh, yes ! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this.
Firstly, you could try constructing the product automaton M(Q, Σ, δ, q, F), where Q is the cartesian product of the sets A(Q) and B(Q) where, A is an automaton which accepts all strings having 11 as a substring and B accepts all strings having 010 as a substring. A state S(p, q) in M is final if p ∈ A(F) and q ∈ B(F).
Secondly, it's not hard to convinced yourself that for a string to be accepted by M, the string could either have 11 followed by some substring and then a 010, or the other way around. This intuition might help you make a DFA, without having to construct the product automaton. Here's the DFA.
[image: DFA]

Comment: That clears up tons! Thank you so much!!